# Which tensorflow method does decide to a particular batch of examples is for the model to learn?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the implementation of SGD in tensorflow.

I began with [gradient_descent.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py) because of the file name.

Per [keras doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer), an optimizer needs to implement `_resource_apply_dense` method, which corresponds with [the code (partly)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15d5b930d7e6e4463e275cfcff22042105148e3f/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py#L129) shown below:

```
def _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var, apply_state=None):
    var_device, var_dtype = var.device, var.dtype.base_dtype
    coefficients = ((apply_state or {}).get((var_device, var_dtype))
                    or self._fallback_apply_state(var_device, var_dtype))

    if self._momentum:
    momentum_var = self.get_slot(var, "momentum")
    return gen_training_ops.ResourceApplyKerasMomentum(
        ...
```

I'd like to know who passes the `var` variable to the `_resource_apply_dense` method? In other words, which method decides this particular batch of examples is for the model to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [optimizer_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/da6568a4d354c8863ecbb8991817e546c5f361e5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L701) or tensorflow keras, we find the only use of this function in the entire tensorflow codebase:

```py
   #...
   def apply_grad_to_update_var(var, grad):
      #...
      if "apply_state" in self._dense_apply_args:
        apply_kwargs["apply_state"] = apply_state
      update_op = self._resource_apply_dense(grad, var, **apply_kwargs)
      if var.constraint is not None:
        with ops.control_dependencies([update_op]):
          return var.assign(var.constraint(var))
```

We later see on that same file that the `var` variable comes from an argument to the `_distributed_apply` function:

```py
#...
def _distributed_apply(self, distribution, grads_and_vars, name, apply_state):
    #...
    with name_scope_only_in_function_or_graph(name or self._name):
      for grad, var in grads_and_vars:
      #...
```

Finally, the `grads_and_vars` argument is defined as [`List of (gradient, variable) pairs`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/da6568a4d354c8863ecbb8991817e546c5f361e5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L618) in the function [`apply_gradients`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/da6568a4d354c8863ecbb8991817e546c5f361e5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L593):

```py
  #...
  def apply_gradients(self,
                      grads_and_vars,
    #...
    """...
    Args:
      grads_and_vars: List of (gradient, variable) pairs.
    """
```

If you check the occurrences of `apply_gradients` ([this search](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?q=apply_gradients)), you will see that it is a common way to update the weights of the network, and is thus controlled by the "update" step of the optimizer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just before [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/da6568a4d354c8863ecbb8991817e546c5f361e5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L640)

    `self._create_all_weights(var_list)`

I inserted 

    `print(var_list[0].numpy(), var_list[1].numpy())` and then I got weights and bias, rather than the training examples, any ideas?

Comment: Note that `var_list` is a list of trainable variables, not a list of training examples! you're touching code related to the update of trainable variables!

Answer (score 0):

These are two different questions:

1. **The caller**: *"who passes the `var` variable to the `_resource_apply_dense` method?"*
2. **Particular examples**: *"which method decides this particular batch of examples is for the model to learn?"*

### 1. The caller

The main function that updates weights in any TensorFlow optimizer is `apply_gradients`, and it receives a zip of trainable weights and their gradients. `var` is a list of trainable weights unzipped in this [line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L709). From my understanding, here is the call sequence:

1. [`apply_gradients`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L592-L675) **calls** `_distributed_apply`.
2. [`_distributed_apply`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L677-L737), **calls** an inner `apply_grad_to_update_var`.
3. [`apply_grad_to_update_var`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L680-L704) **calls** inherited and custom  `_resource_apply_dense` or `_resource_apply_sparse`.

### 2. Particular examples

The decision on which examples are picked for a model to learn has nothing to do with the optimizer. **Optimizers decide the amount in which the weights will be changed**, it can be just the gradients, and it can be something more, **and then they apply the change**.

A batch is a subset of data. Thus, you can specify the data yourself or allow other classes to decide for you like *Dataset* class (please check [`shuffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) function).